why is my higher order function returning true and false?
I have to create my own higher order filter() function to filter an array of 10 words that only returns word that have 6 or more letters but my function is only returning true and false and not omitting words that are not 6 or more letters instead of actually returning the words in a new array. Do add additional code to execute the function?
Also I am not allowed to use the built-in filter function.
const wordArray = ["mine", "script", "function", "array", "javascript", "python", "coding", "html", "css", "bye"];
//myFilterFunction(HOF) takes an array (arr) and hypothetical function (fn) as arguments//
let myFilterFunction = (arr) => (fn) => {
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(fn(arr[i]));
    }
    return newArray; //return a array
};
//myFilterFunction is used with an anonymous function to return whether each word is 6 or more   letters//
const printArray = myFilterFunction(wordArray)((word) => word.length >= 6);
//Output the result to the console//
console.log("this array only contains words that are 6 letters or more: " + printArray);


That is due to the fact that you push the result of your predicate to the result array instead of pushing based on the result of the predicate.

Your myFilterFunction() function creates what is essentially a .map() mapper with a fixed mapping function; it is not in any way a "filter" because in all cases every element from the source array is transformed and included in the result. When you pass in a "filter" function (actually a mapping function) that returns a boolean result, you will of course get an array filled with true or false.

You were appending the result of the function that you have passed as argument into the array instead of passing the elements of array
const wordArray = ["mine", "script", "function", "array", "javascript", "python", "coding", "html", "css", "bye"];
//myFilterFunction(HOF) takes an array (arr) and hypothetical function (fn) as arguments
let myFilterFunction = (arr) => (fn) => {
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
      fn(arr[i]) && newArray.push(arr[i]);
//if the condition is true we are adding the element to newArray 

    }
    return newArray; //return a array
};
//myFilterFunction is used with an anonymous function to return whether each word is 6 or more   letters
const printArray = myFilterFunction(wordArray)((word) => word.length >= 6);
//Output the result to the console
console.log("this array only contains words that are 6 letters or more: " + printArray);


You are pushing the boolean expression result of the condition instead use that as a condition to push the desired word like so
const wordArray = ["mine", "script", "function", "array", "javascript", "python", "coding", "html", "css", "bye"];
//myFilterFunction(HOF) takes an array (arr) and hypothetical function (fn) as arguments//
let myFilterFunction = (arr) => (fn) => {
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (fn(arr[i])) {
            newArray.push(arr[i]);   
        }
    }
    return newArray; //return a array
};
//myFilterFunction is used with an anonymous function to return whether each word is 6 or more   letters//
const printArray = myFilterFunction(wordArray)((word) => word.length >= 6);
//Output the result to the console//
console.log("this array only contains words that are 6 letters or more: " + printArray);

